# Checking Model State On GET Requests necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm noticing code which is apparently written this way for security purposes but I'm confused by it.  I was under the impression **ModelState.IsValid** is meant for checking POST data, but not an initial GET request.

Can anybody explain how this is a security issue that model state would need to be checked on an initial GET?

Comment: It has nothing to do with security. `ModelState.IsValid` checks if the model has any validation errors.

Comment: correct, but on a get request where the model is not populated from user data, is it necessary to check it's valid?

Comment: What model? Do you really have a GET method which has a model as a parameter? Its not really clear what your asking. Perhaps an example of the method you calling and how you calling it would help explain.